# CSS Style First Letter of Every Paragraph Following an H1?

Tags: html, css

I need to increase the font-size to 200% of every first letter of every paragraph that is following an H1 (header).

i.e.

```
<h1> This is a header </h1>
<p>The first 'T' in this paragraph needs to be set to 200%</p>

<ul>
   <li>Random list item 1</li>
   <li>Random list item 2</li>
</ul>

<p>The first 'T' in this paragraph does NOT need to be set to 200% as it doesn't follow an H1</p>
```

The closest I've gotten is using p::first-letter {font-size: 200%;} but that clearly doesn't work as it selects the first letter of every paragraph. I have been googling and trying to figure out how to select just the ones that follow an H1 forever now. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `h1 + p::first-letter`:

```css
h1 + p::first-letter {font-size: 200%;}
```

```html
<h1> This is a header </h1>
<p>The first 'T' in this paragraph needs to be set to 200%</p>

<ul>
   <li>Random list item 1</li>
   <li>Random list item 2</li>
</ul>

<p>The first 'T' in this paragraph does NOT need to be set to 200% as it doesn't follow an H1</p>
```

The `+` selects only the [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) (in this case, only a `<p>` that immediatley follows a `<h1>`).

Comment: That is it! I knew it was something so simple, but for some reason I couldn't piece it together with the use of Google. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it might help you

h1 ~ p:first-letter {font-size: 200%;}

Answer (score 0):

```css
span{
font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>f</span>irst text styled font</h1>
```